# Display page only if ajax call succeeds?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a subdomain protected by a service similar to cloudflare. It checks if a visitor is human or not. To save bandwidth usage I want only one file to be loaded from this subdomain as indicator if the visitor is a bot or not. If it is not loaded, the service has blocked it as bot, and nothing should be shown.

I already thought of an ajax request before the page loads to check this.

```
var success = 0;
function myCall() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "sub.example.com/hello.php",
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html"
    });

request.done(function() {
    // Load page, because the request was successfull   

$.ajax({
     url: 'content.php', //This is the current file
     type: "POST",
     dataType:'json', // add json datatype to get json
     data: ({load: true}),
     success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
     }
     }) 
    });
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @adeneo Yes thats fine, the file which is loaded from the subdomain is protected by a third party provider which will scan the request and analyze it. It is the same as when a visitor would open sub.exmaple.com it only saves traffic this way.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
var success = 0;
function myCall() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "sub.example.com/hello.php",
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'content.php', //This is the current file
                type: "POST",
                data: dat,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error:  function(data){
                    console.log('Error!');
                }
            }); 
        },
        error:  function(data){
                    console.log('Error!');
        }
});
}
```

Comment: I get this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: remove one of `})` from the end.